# Selenium WebDriver Internet Explorer Ventanas Emergente

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Necesito de su ayuda nuevamente, estoy realizando la automatización de un flujo utilizando Selenium + Java, cuando ejecuto el script en Google Chrome funciona de mil maravillas pero cuando lo hago en Internet Explorer tengo problemas, por que en un paso se despliega una nueva ventana (No es una pestaña en el navegador) pero no sigue el flujo se queda en el home para realizar el login.[image: Problema Presentado]

Lo cual me estalla la automatizacion por que no logra continuar el proceso, por favor si alguien me puede ayudar con el tema.

Answer (score 0):

Un problema que tuve con IE8, no se que version estas usando, fue que el windows handles no me devolvia el total de ventanas reales que habia. Tenia que moverme a default content y luego pedirle las ventanas. Repito esto solo fué para IE8.

Algo asi:

```
// Save the parent
parent = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        if (!winHandle.equals(parent)) {
        // Do something
        }
}
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(parent);
```